# Twitter API v.1.1: How to prevent special commands (SMS) for POST statuses/update?

Tags: twitter, oauth, escaping

I'm trying to figure out how to allow posting of [special commands](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14020-twitter-for-sms-basic-features) during statuses/update. the [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) stats that if post tweets stating with "D ", "M " it will send a direct message to the user after the command.

I tried replacing the first character with a "no-break space" (%A0). However twitter translates these characters to �.

The only other option I can think of is creating a regex which strips out all potentially hazardous SMS code. This isn't ideal since I would prefer to keep the raw tweet. Such as tweeting: "D Day was an alright movie." would result in "Day was an alright movie."

I also tried entering a space before the post but it just got ignored and still sent a direct message. Is there some sort of escape character or cheat to make twitter ignore these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the solution. There were a few issues. 1st was my percent encoding function wasn't accepting unicode characters so twitter was responding with a �. To resolve this I used the following code in VB.Net:

```
Regex.Replace(Uri.EscapeDataString(s), "[\!\*\'\(\)]", Function(m) Uri.HexEscape(Convert.ToChar(m.Value(0).ToString())))
```

The second issue is twitter treats all white space characters the same. So you can't cheat and use a character such as u+00A0 (No-break space) or any other character listed in:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf (6.4)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Luckily twitter does not include [zero-width spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) as a white space character. As well twitter actually allows for 141 characters to be posted through the API if using a zero-width space. This means you can add U+200B after the SMS command and before the space to prevent the SMS command from running. Such as:

```
Dim s as String = "M" & ChrW(8203) & " Username 140 character tweet posted here as a test. This is actually 141 characters because of the zero-width space. But accepted anyway."
```

Hope this helps!

Update:

For those who are looking for the regex code to do this, it's a 1 liner:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "^(ON|OFF|FOLLOW|F|UNFOLLOW|LEAVE|L|STOP|QUIT|END|CANCEL|UNSBSCRIBE|ARRET|D|M|RETWEET|RT|SET|WHOIS|W|GET|G|FAV|FAVE|FAVORITE|FAVORITE|\*|STATS|SUGGEST|SUG|S|WTF|HELP|INFO|AIDE|BLOCK|BLK|REPORT|REP)( )", Function(m) m.ToString.Replace(" ", ChrW(8203) & " "))
```